# Async/await - any changes in .NET 4.6 or .NET Core?

Tags: c#, async-await

**Hi All**,

I plan to develop a **custom awaiter** quite similar to one presented in this brilliant article:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/24/how-to-hibernate-async-methods-how-to-serialize-task.aspx

In short, it allows serializing the state of an async method, to be deserialized and resumed at a later time.

**My concern** is that the implementation (for .NET 4.5) is based on a hack of accessing a private field `m_stateMachine` of struct `AsyncMethodBuilderCore`, which is an internal type in **mscorlib**.

**I edited the question** following @Peter's comment:

I wonder if anyone who installed .NET 4.6 or .NET Core (ASP.NET 5) previews and investigated async/await in those versions, saw any change in how the compiler generates the state machine behind async/await, compared to .NET 4.5?

**Some background**

I am exploring possibility of authoring long-running workflows (similar to those provided by Windows Workflow Foundation) using C# async/await syntax. Which means that in my case, async/await must be backed by persistence and tracking mechanisms. Then the code of a workflow would look like this:

```
public class ProcessingWorkflowOfForm12345C : AbstractWorkflow<Form12345C>
{
    private readonly ExternalServices _services;

    public ProcessingWorkflowOfForm12345C(ExternalServices services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public override async void Run(Form12345C form)
    {
        while ( form.ExtraDocumentsRequired )
        {
            var extraDocuments = await _services.RequestExtraDocuments(
                form.GetRequiredExtraDocuments()); // can take weeks
            form.AddExtraDocuments(extraDocuments);
        }

        var approvalResult = _services.AutoApprove(form);

        while ( true )
        {
            switch ( approvalResult )
            {
                case ApprovalResult.Approved:
                    form.SetApproved();
                    return;
                case ApprovalResult.Rejected:
                    form.SetRejected();
                    return;
                case ApprovalResult.Manual:
                    approvalResult = 
                        await _services.RequestManualApproval(form); // can take days
                    break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using asynchrony in your flow? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Microsoft knows but is not obliged to tell. It's your risk. To me at first sight it seems you are misusing the mechanism for something it wasn't designed for.

Comment: Side note: async-await does not need Tasks - you should consider creating your completely custom serializable Awaitable objects...

Comment: Thanks for the comments! 

Yuval and Ondrej: I am trying to provide developers with the most productive ways of getting their work done fast. I agree that most likely my use case was not one of async/await design goals. Which is too bad, because if you just read C# of the example, it makes perfect sense, don't you agree?

Alexei: Absolutely, this is exactly what I'm going to do.

Comment: @Alexei Tasks or custom awaitable, the state machine he wants to serialize will still exist.

Comment: Asynchrony's by product is increasing throughput. I'm not to keen on how this will help you here?

Comment: In this case, I am "profiling" developer's effort and not the runtime performance. Avoid activities that consume time, like going into designers. I am convinced that throwing 40 lines of C# code is the fastest solution. As for runtime, I don't expect to gain any extra performance compared to alternative approaches.

Comment: It might be just me, but i still cannot get my head around why you find serialization of the state machine appealing in any way, given it may change in any future release of the framework, causing your code to break. Not only that, but by also relying on it in your implementation would cause any future developer that might be the one fixing your code due to framework changes to have intimate knowledge of an implementation detail of the framework. I would run from that like burning fire.

Comment: At best, the question is too broad. Also, any answer involves primarily speculation (a sort of opinion), and so is ill-suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh no, that was not my intention, I wasn't looking for opinions or speculations. I probably need to rephrase the question. I wanted to know, if anyone who installed .NET 4.6 or .NET Core (ASP.NET 5) previews, investigated async/await and saw any evidence of change in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The state machine generator has not changed, it's still exactly the same. The only thing that changed starting with .NET Core 2.1 is the new type `AsyncStateMachineBox` replaced `MoveNextRunner`.

You can find source code that accesses fields of a state machine for serialization here:
https://github.com/Dasync/Dasync/tree/master/Engine/AsyncStateMachine

P.S. there are obvious benefits of using compiler-generated state machines for distributed computing. As of today, this can be viewed as a hack, perhaps tomorrow it comes as a built-in language support.
[Conquest of Distributed Systems (part 4) — The Now and the Vision](https://medium.com/@sergiis/conquest-of-distributed-systems-part-4-the-now-and-the-vision-e844c9aee2c7)